# (Proof verification) Prove that $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ if $|f'(x)|<1 $ for all $ x\in(0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})=L$, I must show that $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)=L$ if  $|f'(x)|<1 $ for all $ x\in(0,1]$. I tried proving this by first letting $\epsilon>0$. Then, find $\delta>0$ such that for $0<x<\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

So, let $\epsilon>0$. Then, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N \implies |f(\frac{1}{n})-L|$. Let $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$. Let $x < \frac{1}{N}$. Since the function is differentiable on $(0,1]$, it's also differentiable on any interval within $(0,1]$. Hence, we can find some $n$ such that $x<\frac{1}{n}$ where I can find $\mu \in (x,\frac{1}{n})$ such that  $$f'(\mu) = \frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}-x}$$ by the Mean Value Theorem. Since $f'(\mu) < 1$, the above equation implies  $$f(\frac{1}{n})-f(x) < \frac{1}{n}-x$$ $$\implies |f(\frac{1}{n})-f(x)| < |\frac{1}{n}-x|<\delta$$ $$\implies |L-f(x)| < |x| < \delta$$ as $n\to\infty$. If I let $\delta = \epsilon$, then it proves $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x) = L$.

Comment: So, just to brush off the trivialities... $f$ is assumed differentiable (and thus continuous) on $(0,1]$, but there is no continuity assumption at $0$, right?

Comment: There's at least some confusion between $n$ and $N$.

Comment: Besides, you can't change $\delta$ once you have chosen it.

Comment: @ClementC.Yes, since $f'(x)$ always exists for the interval (0,1]. But $f$ is not assumed to be continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: it is known that

**Lemma:** Let $X,Y$ metric spaces, $A\subseteq X$. If $f:A\to Y$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:\bar{A}\to Y$ by defining $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in A$ and, $g(x)=\lim f(x_{n})$ if $x\not\in A$ and $(x_{n})$ is any sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.

Let $A=(0,1]$. If $f_{A}'$ is bounded, then $f_{A}$ is uniformly continuous. Let $g$ be the extension of the lemma. Since $f(1/n)\to f(0)$, $g=f$.